# ActiveRecord and PG gem gives different results when comparaing dates with time zone

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5, pg

Using ActiveRecord 5.0.1 we get wrong results when comparing 2 dates with time zone.

We get  : `14:30 paris time < 14:00 paris time => true`

Example :

I convert 13:00 in UTC to paris time, i get 14:00 :

```
SELECT ('2017-01-25 13:00:00.00000'::TIMESTAMP at time zone 'UTC' at time zone 'Europe/Paris')::TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE
=> 2017-01-25 14:00:00+01
```

If i compare 14:30 in paris time < 13:00 in UTC converted to paris time (i.e 14:00) i get FALSE

```
SELECT ('2017-01-25 14:30:00.00000+01'::TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE < ('2017-01-25 13:00:00.00000'::TIMESTAMP at time zone 'UTC' at time zone 'Europe/Paris')::TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE)
=> false
```

This works with PG gem :

```
> conn.exec("SELECT ('2017-01-25 14:30:00.00000+01'::TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE < ('2017-01-25 13:00:00.00000'::TIMESTAMP at time zone 'UTC' at time zone 'Europe/Paris')::TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE)")[0]
=> {"?column?"=>"f"}
```

This fails with ActiveRecord :

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("SELECT ('2017-01-25 14:30:00.00000+01'::TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE < ('2017-01-25 13:00:00.00000'::TIMESTAMP at time zone 'UTC' at time zone 'Europe/Paris')::TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE)")[0]
=> {"?column?"=>true}
```

We have a PostgreSQL function that returns very different results when executed via PSQL or via ActiveRecord and we think we have isolated the problem with this behavior.

Does anybody know how we can get the date comparison to work with Activerecord ?